# Connecting Power BI to Civi

Tags: civireport

Has anyone tried to connect Civi to Power BI?  I'm considering using this platform for some more in depth analytics.

Comment: How did it work out? I am considering the same

Comment: We've had to put this on the back-burner for the moment but we did encounter some issues that were making it difficult to make a connection.  Our challenges revolved around creating a secure bridge between PowerBI and the SQL database.  There are some services that help in creating that bridge but we didn't get that figured out before pausing this project.

Comment: Thx for reply. I just discovered that Power BI Desktop doesn’t come with a Mac version either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe anyone has, but Power BI has a MySQL connector component, so it appears that would be all you need:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/integrations/mysql/

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  We'll give it a try and see how it goes.

Answer (score 5):

Connecting with API could be a better solution. This is how I did it:

**Step 1: Prepare data in CiviCRM**

- Get the site key
- Create a CiviCRM and Drupal user with correct access rights
- Get(Create) the API-key of that user
- Create a data processor with relevant data, accessed with API
- First column to be an index key, used to connect with other CiviCRM data sources
- Amounts to be Aggregate functions, 2 decimals, comma as decimal separator,
  and space as thousand separator
- Avoid including any personal information in the data processor API-call, than there will be no privacy risk involved with PowerBI.
- With data processor API calls, only get-function is available. That means no risk of anyone updating/creating values in
  database
- Test by input URL to a browser

https://[site-URL]/[CiviCRM folder]?entity=[name of API-call or data processor]&action=get&api_key=[api-key of a CiviCRM&Drupal user with proper access rights]&key=[Site key]&version=[API version]&json{"sequential":1,"options":{"limit":0}}

**Step 2: Proxy (if relevant)**

- Add API-call to CiviProxy
- Get different site URL, CiviCRM folder, Api-key and site keys
- Build up a new URL
- Test by input URL to a browser

**Step 3: Connect Power BI**

- Get data with Web connection
- Input URL that is tested after proxy

**Step 4: Create graphs and statistics in PowerBI**

- Transform columns to correct data type!
- Schedule automatical refresh(es). Daily at 03.00 am is
  a good suggestion,
  as that will likely not cause any performance issues in CiviCRM
- Connect different data sources in Power BI, like website traffic