# CiviCRM and SharePoint

Tags: contacts

We run both CiviCRM and SharePoint. I've looked at the CiviCRM SharePoint extension, but:

1. It didn't work - it gave errors.
2. We are looking at exposing CiviCRM contacts in SharePoint - we don't need document sets, but just an external list with the CiviCRM data.

It looks as though SharePoint likes to get external data via the Odata format. Has anyone any experience of that?

I suppose it might be possible to devise something that populated SharePoint list from contacts, perhaps based on the SharePoint extension.

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe add the errors you got?

Comment: I tried re-installing CiviCRM SharePoint, but can't set it up because you need to log in on the CiviCRM SharePoint setup screen. That didn't work because the library is a required field and you can't get that until you have logged on, so Catch-22 applies, it seems. Either  that or there is an issue with MFA and the SharePoint account.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show CiviCRM data in Office 365, I would rather considering using Microsoft Power BI.

https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/39681

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. We want to use CiviCRM as the authoritative source of contact details in SharePoint rather than someone maintaining another list. The idea of a data processor (I need to learn what that is) seems a good one. I've been exploring REST. I haven't discovered how SharePoint could read JSON or even if it can.